# Laplace transform of a resonant second-order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following ODE with the Laplace transform $y'' + y = \cos \omega t$ with initial conditions $y(0)=y'(0)=0$.

I get $Y(s) = \frac{s}{(s^2 + 1)^2}$ but then, I don't know how to compute the inverse transformation. Decomposing this fraction into partial fractions does not help in this specific case, which seems to involve resonance. How would you use the inverse Laplace transform to get the final solution? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Source: [Inverse Laplace Transform partial fraction $\frac{\omega ^{2}}{\left ( s^{2}+\omega ^{2} \right )( s^{2}+\omega ^{2} )}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868194/inverse-laplace-transform-partial-fraction-frac-omega-2-left-s2-om)

By taking the derivative $\frac{d}{d \omega} \mathcal{L}(\cos \omega t) = \mathcal{L}(- t \sin \omega t) = \frac{d}{d \omega} \frac{s}{s^2 + \omega^2} = - \frac{2 \omega s}{(s^2 + \omega^2)^2}$. The derivative commutes with the Laplace transform in this case since we derive w.r.t. $\omega$ while the Laplace transform integrates w.r.t. $t$.

Finally, fix $\omega=1$, so we obtain $\mathcal{L}(t \sin t) = \frac{2s}{(s^2+1)^2}$ and then $y(t) = \frac{1}{2} t \sin t$.

Comment: Why did you ask for help if you already knew how to solve the problem?

Comment: After writing the question, Stack Exchange recommended looking at some existing questions and I found the one that I cited as the source. I completed the exercise and then I hesitated to remove it, but then I read this [link](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.53439528.1446735456.1709907132-2099619096.1708809681) so I decided to post it anyway in case it can help someone else. I'm ok to remove it if you think it is not useful.